# Secrets with containerized single-node kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes

It is well known that secrets don't work with containerized kubernetes cluster ((https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.md). There are several bugs logged for this (For instance: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/18239).

However, with Docker 1.10 allowing shared/slave propagation, this issue is supposed to have technically resolved. However, I am having trouble getting this to work.

I tried changing the single node docker command like so:

```
docker run \
 --restart=always \
 --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
 --volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
 --volume=/dev:/dev \
 --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:shared \
 --volume=/var/lib/kubelet/:/var/lib/kubelet:shared \
 --volume=/var/run:/var/run:shared \
 --net=host \
 --pid=host \
 --privileged=true \
 -d \
 gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube-amd64:v${K8S_VERSION} \
 /hyperkube kubelet \
  --containerized \
  --hostname-override="127.0.0.1" \
  --address="0.0.0.0" \
  --api-servers=http://localhost:8080 \
  --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests \
  --cluster-dns=10.0.0.10 \
  --cluster-domain=cluster.local \
  --allow-privileged=true \
  --v=10
```

Please note the **shared** mount propagation setting. When I do this, i get the error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: Cannot start container
>   f7a5ae3d3e88b02ba42544ec768050717c942bc62889175171e6ebb3f89a1a6c: Path
>   /var/run is mounted on /run but it is not a shared mount..

I am trying to do this on a Unbutu trusty on a vagrant box. I am using docker version 1.10.0 and containerized hyperkuber version v1.2.0-alpha.7.

What am I missing here? If I roll back the shared setting with the original **rw**, I get the error: **Unable to mount volumes for pod** with the **IsLikelyNotMountPoint** error.

### **UPDATE**

Hey Guys, I think I figured it out (at least for the single node containerized kubernetes environment). The steps I followed was:

`mkdir -p /var/lib/kubelet
mount -o bind /var/lib/kubelet /var/lib/kubelet
mount --make-shared /var/lib/kubelet`

and the the actual command

`docker run \
    --restart=always \
    --volume=/:/rootfs:ro \
    --volume=/sys:/sys:ro \
    --volume=/dev:/dev \
    --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:rw \
    --volume=/var/lib/kubelet/:/var/lib/kubelet:shared \
    --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw \
    --net=host \
    --pid=host \
    --privileged=true \
    -d \
    gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube-amd64:v${K8S_VERSION} \
    /hyperkube kubelet \
        --hostname-override="127.0.0.1" \
        --address="0.0.0.0" \
        --api-servers=http://localhost:8080 \
        --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests \
        --cluster-dns=10.0.0.10 \
        --cluster-domain=cluster.local \
        --allow-privileged=true --v=10`

I am using kubernetes version v1.2.0.alpha.7. Also please note that in the main command, I added the *shared* mount and removed the "containerized" parameter. Also, I am using the latest version of Docker (1.10)

Comment: If this helps, Docker 1.10 isn't supported by Kubernetes yet, see issue #19720 https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/19720

Comment: Thanks janetkuo. The impression I get from the kubernetes community is that for the containerized hyperkube, there really is no need for change to take advantage of the new propagation options in docker 1.10. I could be wrong but I would love for someone to confirm it.

Comment: Thanks Jan Garaj for the edits. Its more readable.

Comment: I think you are trail-blazing here.  I have not yet played with docker's support for shared mounts, myself, and I expect many people have not either.

Comment: @GopinathTaget are you still having trouble?  I think we worked through this one.  Could you update the question?

Comment: @PaulMorie We moved away from a containerized kubernetes as it turned out to be more problem than its worth. The last problem we had was that it opened double the file handles compared to a non-dockerized installation of kubernetes. I might revisit dockerized kubernetes some time later when it is more stable presumably.